# Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2 : get changes to PersistentCollection

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence

I am building an application where the user can edit some data and then gets presented with a screen where he can confirm (and comment on) his edits.

In the confirmation form I display the changes that have been made to the entity. This works for "normal" fields. Here is some code that works for checking a single field:

```
// create $form
// bind $form

if ($form->isValid() {
    $data = $form->getData();
    // example, get changes of a "normal" field
    if ($data['color'] != $entity->getColor()) {
        // do something with changes
    }
}
```

But I can't do the same for a relation (example ManyToMany with Users) :

```
    if ($data['users'] != $entity->getUsers()
```

doesn't work because $data['users'] and $entity->getUsers() refer to the same persistent collection. It is possible to call this function to see if there are changes:

```
    if ($data['users']->isDirty())
```

but it isn't possible to see what changes were made.

The second problem with the above is that if all items are removed from the persistent collection, Doctrine does not mark it as "changed" (isDirty() = true), so I can't catch the specific change where the user removes all "users" from the entity in the form.

Please note that the code all works, the only problem I have is that I am unable to view/process the changes made on the confirmation step.

Comment: Retrieve $entity->getUsers() before bind?  Also check and see if your formtype is adding the field by reference.

Comment: @Lighthart that's a good idea (by reference)! Will check and get back to you...

Comment: @Lighthart doesn't work because the by reference is for collections and not for Entity for fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the original collection in a variable before bind and then compared the new collection after bind.  PHP has quite a few array comparison functions, and collections are readily turned into native arrays by $collection->toArray();

eg:

```
// create form
$oldusers=$entity->getUsers()->toArray();
// bind form
if ($form->isValid() {
    $data = $form->getData();
    if ($data['users'] != $oldusers) {
        // do something with changes
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, after the bind $oldusers also gets updated with the changes. This is because $oldusers refers to the same collection.

Comment: Edited above.  Just cast it as an array.  There is _no_ way an array and an object can be the same memory location.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using that toArray(). I added my final solution too in case anyone wants to comment/improve it.

Comment: Should that be `$oldusers=$entity->getUsers()->toArray();` I am prohibited from editting/fixing just one character :D

Comment: Fixed per CM's comment

Answer (score 8):

[`Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php) has internal API (public) methods `getSnapshot`, `getDeleteDiff`, `getInsertDiff` that can be used during lifecycle events of the `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork`. You could for example check the insert diff of a persistent collection during `onFlush`.

Comment: thanks +1, but those methods don't work if the entire collection has been wiped (the isDirty() is also a method from PersistentCollection) and this is my main problem.

Comment: You should use these methods after changesets were computed (during `flush`)

Comment: Problem is that I need to show the changes for the user to accept/cancel which means I can't call onFlush()

Answer (score 6):

Solved it like this:

1) To get changes that will be made directly to the Entity, use the following:

```
// create form
// bind form
// form isValid()

$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->computeChangeSets();
$changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
print_r($changeset);
```

2a) To get changes to the relations, use the answer from Lighthart above:

```
$oldUsers = $entity->getUsers()->toArray();
// bind form
// form isValid
$newUsers = $entity->getUsers()->toArray();
// compare $oldUsers and $newUsers
```

2b) Use these methods on Persistent Collection to find inserts / deletes:

```
$newUsers = $entity->getUsers();
$inserted = $newUsers->getDeleteDiff();
$deleted  = $newUsers->getInsertDiff();
```

The only problem with (2b) is that if ALL users are removed and none added then getDeleteDiff() is empty which appears to be a Doctrine bug/idiosyncrasy

Comment: I am wrestling with this and wondering where to put this logic. My first thought is controller action, but everyone says keep your controllers skinny. I guess I am looking for an event listener -- either in the Doctrine event system, or Zend Framework 2's event system -- where I can pick this up. I need to clear a cache when certain things happen to an entity's associations.

Comment: Sir its brilliant sir!

Comment: and i didnt faced your problem in 2b, getDeleteDiff() returns array even if all collection items was deleted

Comment: yeah, I guess quite a few Doctrine versions have been released since I first posted this question :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! The hint "if ALL users are removed and none added then getDeleteDiff() is empty which appears to be a Doctrine bug" was very helpful!